# lost in activities

Tags: android, android-activity

I have an Activity that has some form elements. This can be called from other activities..
When the form activity loads, how do I know which one called it?

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easier way is to explicitly indicate that in the intent:

```
Intent i = new Intent(blnah);
i.putExtra("who", "Activity1");
startActivity(intent);
```

Then, on the other activity:

```
// this is the activity with the form
String who = getIntent().getStringExtra("who");
```